# What happens to dead Fomori corpses?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse, werewolf-20th-anniversary, werewolf-the-apocalypse-2nd-edition

What happens to the physical form of a fomor after it’s dead, according to the WtA rulebooks?

I’m preparing a city-based Werewolf game, so I and the players need to take body disposal into account to enforce the Veil.

I’ve gone over a few official sourcebooks, and have read that the bane possessing the person is dispersed when a fomor is killed, but I can’t find a mention of what happens to their physical remains.

So do the physical corpses of fomori melt, vanish, evaporate, turn to dust, get up and walk it off?

Or are Garou left to dispose of a human body (if they’re very lucky) or a mass of malformed flesh?

Or is this all storyteller’s choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Werewolf: The Apocalypse [Fianna tribebook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565043251) (page 18-19) has a section describing the Fomori Wars, in which the Fianna battled fomori. This section explicitly describes fomori leaving corpses:

> The Wyrm's forces would gather bodies from the field, both fomor and fallen Gorou, and animate them to return to fight again and again.

The Fianna learned to decapitate their fallen to prevent this reanimation.

Comment: At the same time, I'd guess it's probably up to dramatic license and/or needs of the story. Since fomor can be as different from one another as a vampire is from a werewolf, one type may typically leave a corpse, another a puddle, and another nothing at all. I'd think weaker ones would probably be more likely to leave normal corpses.

Comment: @Uueerdo Are there any extant descriptions of fomori melting or dusting when killed? I will look through some other things later, it would be an interesting contrast.

Comment: Not that I know of; I'm just saying stuff that isn't clearly laid out tends to be left to "storyteller discretion", and one historical account should not be taken as a rule, just a precedent that they _can_ leave bodies.